# Is it possible to get a list of Forces currently active in a D3 Force Simulation?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed, d3-force

Just say I have a `d3-force` simulation, and I add some forces like this:

```
const simulation = d3
    .forceSimulation()
    .nodes(dots)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter());
    .on("tick", tick)
```

Is it possible to list all those forces? Something like a `simulation.getForces()` method for instance? And have it return `["charge", "link", "center"]`.

Comment: Nice question, anyway, but could you elaborate on the use case for this? Because you registered the forces beforehand it's no big deal to keep track of the forces yourself, is it? I mean, the names of your forces are just custom strings not constants of any kind and the forces themselves are mere functions that cannot be told apart by just inspecting those functions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not. From [the source](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/main/src/simulation.js#L23) it looks like the `forces` Map is not exposed at all to the outside. The only workaround I can think is to either wrap the `simulation.force` object and store your own registry (which is hacky), or to keep an array of all possible values and see if `simulation.force(name)` returns anything:

```js
const width = 600,
  height = 600;

const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height]);

const g = svg.append("g");

const nodes = Array
  .from({
    length: 20
  })
  .map(() => {
    const [x, y] = d3.pointRadial(2 * Math.PI * Math.random(), 200);
    return {
      id: Math.random(),
      x,
      y
    };
  });

simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(20))
  .force("manyBody", d3.forceManyBody().strength(30))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter().strength(0.01))
  .alpha(0.1)
  .alphaDecay(0)
  .nodes(nodes)
  .on("tick", () => {
    g.selectAll("circle:not(.exit)")
      .data(simulation.nodes(), d => d.id)
      .join(
        enter => enter.append("circle")
        .attr("fill", d => d3.interpolateSinebow(d.id))
        .attr("r", 1)
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("r", 19)
        .selection(),
        update => update
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y),
        exit => exit
        .classed("exit", true)
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("fill", "#eee")
        .attr("r", 1)
        .remove()
      );
  });

const allPossibleForces = [
  "x",
  "y",
  "manyBody",
  "collide",
  "center"
];

const allForces = allPossibleForces.filter(v => simulation.force(v) !== undefined);
console.log(allForces);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```